# Disable one2many popup odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

Good Day! is it possible to disable pop of tree view in the form. I tried no_open="True" readonly="1" edit="False" both on field and tree view but didn't worked.

```
                        <field name="payment_line">
                            <tree editable="top" create="false">
                                <field name="product"/>
                                <field name="description"/>
                                <field name="account"/>
                                <field name="unit"/>
                                <field name="qty"/>
                                <field name="amount"/>
                                <field name="total"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've coped with the same issue in odoo 10, my one2many treeview always make a popup on click. No matter editable='bottom' option was set.

Suddenly I've found **web_tree_no_open** module from [codingforfun](https://github.com/codingforfun), that adds a new option:

< tree open="false" >

It's for version 8 but it can be used in 10 just renaming **openerp**.py to **manifest**.py

It can be downloaded from here:

https://github.com/initOS/web/tree/8.0-tree-view-no-select/web_tree_no_open

Worked for me, I hope it helps

Comment: @CodeFarmer How can we achieve this in Odoo 11 ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this style to disable click in read as well as edit mode:

```
<field name="your_o2m" style="pointer-events:none;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `editable='bottom'` in this case, like:

```
     <field name='line_ids'>
        <tree create='false' editable='bottom'>
            <field name='so_line_id' readonly='1'/>
       <tree>
     </field>
```

Comment: Checked Not working readonly on tree view work only onedit not on read

Comment: "tree view work only onedit not on read" ?? please explain it,( initially you have asked " is it possible to disable pop of tree view in the form" and i have answered for it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried your method but didn't work. i add create="false" editable="bottom" and still on click popup come up. I am using odoo 9

Comment: you are using  editable="top"   , use editable='bottom', and create='false' non necessary for it

Comment: editable="bottom" still not working..! i think you didn't get it when i click the tree view on save mode it doesnt work on edit mode it's fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110144/discussion-between-prakash-sharma-and-omeed-totakhel).

Answer (score 1):

Odoo Version 10.0

[web_tree_no_open](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/web_tree_no_open/) module adds a new option: `<tree open="false">`

Answer (score -1):

**Lists**

The root element of list views is `<tree>` 3. The list view's root can have the following attributes:

**editable**

by default, selecting a list view's row opens the corresponding form view. The editable attributes makes the list view itself editable in-place.

Valid values are top and bottom, making new records appear respectively at the top or bottom of the list.

The architecture for the inline form view is derived from the list view. Most attributes valid on a form view's fields and buttons are thus accepted by list views although they may not have any meaning if the list view is non-editable
default_order

overrides the ordering of the view, replacing the model's default order. The value is a comma-separated list of fields, postfixed by desc to sort in reverse order:

```
<tree default_order="sequence,name desc">
```

**create, edit, delete**

allows disabling the corresponding action in the view by setting the corresponding attribute to false
on_write

only makes sense on an editable list. Should be the name of a method on the list's model. The method will be called with the id of a record after having created or edited that record (in database).

The method should return a list of ids of other records to load or update.
string

alternative translatable label for the view

Deprecated since version 8.0: not displayed anymore

> Note
>
> if the list view is editable, any field attribute from the form view is also valid and will be used when setting up the inline form
>   view

in the form and tree view you can add `create='false'` to disable the create button and `edit='false'` to disable the edit button.Also use editable="top" or editable="bottom" if you dont want the form view to popup. for example

```
<tree string="Sale Order" create="false" edit="false" editable="bottom">
...
...
...
</tree>
```

Comment: I want to stop popup on save mode, on edit mode it's working fine, but when the record is saved and clicked on the list item popup is appearing. any idia how to stop the pop.

Comment: you can do that is odoo JavaScript throw

Comment: Where? Its still the old post not updated could u check plz

Comment: javascript way explained by @Prakash Sharma

Comment: Yes but it will disable all the popup for all record which is again a problem