# Odoo 11 tree (advanced view) to be not open

Tags: odoo-11

I just starting to using odoo 11. i'm using tree, for displaying data of one2many field.

```
<field name="account_ids" nolabel='1'>
    <tree editable="bottom">
        <field name="image" class="oe_avatar" widget="image"/>
        <field name="remark" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

i dont want this field to be open when you click the list

i already read several reference, and tried to:

1. add "open = false", not working
2. add option = {'open': False}, not working
3. add create=False or edit=False, you can't edit or add item again, 
   if you already add item and click it, the open pop up window still appear

i appreciate for your helps! thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826300/disable-one2many-popup-odoo-8

This was once the answer for OpenERP. But doesn't seem to work and I tried fixing it and failed. You may want to have a look.

Comment: hi @Wahyu Indra, I'm encounter the same issue like you, did you solve this?